# How to secure localStorage in HTML5?

Tags: security, html, local-storage

how do we secure the content of HTML5 localStorage from user tampering? In case of cookies, we store information in the encrypted format and the secret used for encrypting will be stored in the server which is unknown to clients.

But, in localStorage the information is residing in the client side and we send the key to the client. So, is there any standard way to secure the information in the localStorage from user tampering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*@Mikko Ohtamaa* is right. it is not so secure to use. but maybe you can use sessionStorage which keep information to session end. and from this [site](http://michael-coates.blogspot.com/2010/07/html5-local-storage-and-xss.html):

> Final Thoughts on Local Storage and Security
>
> 1. Don't use local storage for session identifiers. 
>      Stick with cookies and use the HTTPOnly and Secure flags.
> 2. If cookies won't work for some reason, then use session storage 
>      which will be cleared when the user closes the browser window.
> 3. Be cautious with storing sensitive data in local storage. 
>      Just like any other client side storage options this data can be
>      viewed and modified by the user.

the last thing is that dont store sensitive data in your localStorage...

Answer (score 3):

You don't secure localStorage.

Anything coming from a client software must be untrusted.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone still wondering, check out [SecurityJS.128](https://github.com/Parking-Master/SecurityJS.128) which is a client-side javascript library, and one of the APIs is `window` [`secureStorage`](https://github.com/Parking-Master/SecurityJS.128#windowsecurestorage-api).

---

This is how it works:

```js
(async function() {
    // anonymous function
    // generate the key
    const myKey = securityjs.generateKey();
    // set the item
    secureStorage.setItem("item", "123");

    // lock it
    secureStorage.lock();

    // unlock it
    secureStorage.unlock(myKey);
    // get the item
    secureStorage.getItem("item");
    // "123"
})();
```

Comment: Great find! But the core issue of key being available at client side and user can use the key to tamper the data is still on the table. Original recommendation of not using localstorage for storing sensitive information still holds good.

Comment: That's a good recommendation because data being send over internet (like localStorage) can easily be seen by others and is a big security issue. If you're going to store user information in localStorage then I recommend SecurityJS because it disables the view or editing data from localStorage or sessionStorage. And if you're running a server like Node.js you can store information in databases or variables but don't display it on pages.