# React JS - How do I prevent users from tampering their cookies and gaining access to protected routes/endpoints?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React app wherein the user object is stored as cookies in the App component. This user object has a property `AccountType` which is an integer, and 1 means that the user is a student and 2 means the user is a teacher.

I am using react-router v5 to protect certain routes from being accessed, unless the logged in user is of AccountType 2 (teacher) with the following RouteGuard component:

```js
const RouteGuard = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const user = JSON.parse(Cookies.get("loggedInUser"));
  
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        return user.AccountType === 2 ? (
          <Component />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/403",
              state: {
                error: "You are not allowed to access this resource.",
                from: props.location.pathname,
                redirected: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

And an example of how this RouteGuard component is used:

```js
    <Switch>
      <RouteGuard path="/records" exact component={Records} />
    </Switch>
```

It works well, for normal cases, but I found out that I can login as a student and go to the developer console and in the cookies section, I can modify the cookies and manually set AccountType to 2, thereby bypassing the route protection.

What would be the proper way of preventing unauthorized users from tampering cookies and gaining access to protected endpoints, front-end wise?

Comment: Maybe you should re-implement the authentication to something like this: don't do auth checks in `RouteGuard` component based on the cookie and its value. Instead you can check if there's a cookie present and if it is present, then you could make a request to your API to get the user object. If that request returns 401 or 403 status code, don't let the user in. Otherwise, if you get a 200 response from your API, you will also get that user in the response. So you can let the user in and based on his `AccountType` property, redirect him to the proper route

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disallow this. The best method would be to store a version of any username in the local storage, then compare that data to a server-side database to figure out if that user has the required account type.

This is a similar question:
[How to secure localStorage in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10311103/12973333)

Answer (score 0):

If you get this value from the backend and store it in local storage it will solve your problem. But The best approach will be authenticate using the JWT token and pass the necessary info into it.